# python selenium browsermob-proxy and interceptor

Tags: python, selenium, interceptor, browsermob-proxy

I use python with selenium and browsermob-proxy.
When action occurs ( click, submit), I wish to change http request url.
I don't understand browsermob-proxy explanation:

```
request_interceptor(js)[source]
Executes the java/js code against each response HttpRequest request, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo are available objects to interact with. :param str js: the js/java code to execute
```

```
 server = Server("C:\\browsermob-proxy-2.1.4\\bin\\browsermob-proxy.bat")
   server.start()
   proxy = server.create_proxy()
   request_js = " *** code *** "
   proxy.request_interceptor(request_js)
```

how do I write code in "request_js" in order to change request url?
Is it a possible example?

How do I translate the code below in python?

```
proxy.addRequestFilter(new RequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public HttpResponse filterRequest(HttpRequest request, HttpMessageContents contents, HttpMessageInfo messageInfo) {
                if (messageInfo.getOriginalUri().endsWith("/some-endpoint-to-intercept")) {
                    // retrieve the existing message contents as a String or, for binary contents, as a byte[]
                    String messageContents = contents.getTextContents();

                    // do some manipulation of the contents
                    String newContents = messageContents.replaceAll("original-string", "my-modified-string");
                    //[...]

                    // replace the existing content by calling setTextContents() or setBinaryContents()
                    contents.setTextContents(newContents);
                }

                // in the request filter, you can return an HttpResponse object to "short-circuit" the request
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium, you can interact with a Browser with webdriver.
I'm not sure about what you mean.
Do you mean: when an action caused by code occurs?

If so, the solution is quite simple:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox() # or Chrome or whatever

def redirect(url, *args, **kwargs):
    print("Calling click funtion")
    driver.click(*args, **kwargs)
    print("Redirecting browser")
    webdriver.get(url)
    # Eventually do something else.

# Instead of calling driver.click() call this function
driver.event_and_redirect = redirect
```

Or do you mean: when an action caused by the user on that browser occurs?

If so you can manage that to work in three ways:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

your_url = 'https://www.domain.example'

previous_url = ''

while True:
  url = driver.current_url
  if url != previous_url:
    print(f'Request detected. Redirecting to {your_url}')
    driver.get(your_url)
```

```py
from browsermobproxy import Server
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from haralyzer import HarParser
import time

server = Server(your_server_path)
server.start()
proxy = server.create_proxy()

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy.proxy}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Listend for new requests.
while True:
  proxy.new_har(self._get_current_time(), options=options)
    time.sleep(0.1)
    entries = HarParser(self.proxy.har).har_data['entries']
    if entries != prev_entries:
      print("Requests detected")
      # **You may easily save and modify the har file.**
      # Scrape the main url in the har.
      previous_url = entries[0]['request']['url']
      driver.get(another_url)
    prev_entries = entries
```

```py
import win32api
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
your_url = '' # Url for redirect

width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(1)
midWidth = int((width + 1) / 2)
midHeight = int((height + 1) / 2)

state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  # Left button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128
while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
        state_left = a
        print(a)
        if a < 0:
            print('Left Button Pressed. Redirecting browser')
            driver.get(your_url)
        else:
            # Left button release
            pass
            win32api.SetCursorPos((midWidth, midHeight))
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

I hope this helps you. Tell me if I misunderstood or you need clarification.